# Cannot find package babel-preset-react

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I need help, there was an error while building the application.
Cannot find package 'babel-preset-react' imported from Path\babel-virtual-resolve-base.js

**Installed in devDependencies:**

"@babel/cli": "^7.20.7",

"@babel/core": "^7.20.7",

"@babel/node": "^7.20.7",

"@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^7.20.7",

"@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",

"@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",

"babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",

"babel-jest": "^24.9.0",

"babel-loader": "^8.2.2",

"babel-preset-react-app": "^10.0.1",

"babelify": "^10.0.0",

**In dependencies:**

"grunt-babel": "^8.0.0",

"@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",

**.babelrc:**

{
"presets": [
"@babel/preset-env",
"@babel/preset-react"
]
}

Cannot find package 'babel-preset-react'.
babel-preset-react is babel 6 version, I don't need it. I am using babel version 7.

If I install babel-preset-react a new error occurs.
Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In Path\node_modules\babel-preset-react\lib\index.js

Before that, I migrated from babel 6 to babel 7.
Deleted node_modules and package-lock.json and npm install again

Comment: First, uninstall it and then reinstall it there might be some conflict because of the versions or dependencies

Comment: I did it. didn't help me @ShilpeSaxena

Comment: then check out your react version and the current using dependency version so that neither of them is get deprecated.